# CentOS 7 persistent module loading at boot

Tags: centos, boot, kernel-modules

I need to load the `drbd` module on my CentOS server at boot time. I know a module can be loaded without the need of a restart using `modprobe drbd` but of course after a system reboot I would have to load it again manually. I came across [Persistent Module Loading](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-kernel-modules-persistant.html/) and it says

> Kernel modules are usually loaded directly by the facility that
>   requires them, which is given correct settings in the
>   /etc/modprobe.conf file.

I don't have the conf file, just the `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory.

Next it says:

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux checks for the existence of the
>   /etc/rc.modules file at boot time, which contains various commands to
>   load modules.

So not sure whether this applies only to RHEL or CentOS as well (it's CentOS documentation) but `/etc/rc.modules`was missing as well.

After executing:

```
# echo modprobe foo >> /etc/rc.modules 
# chmod +x /etc/rc.modules
```

I can see the drbd module being loaded even after a reboot:

[image]

Is it ok how I did it ? Second question - the CentOS 7 OS I'm using is for testing purposes - the production system will run on RHEL 7. Would I still apply the same steps to load the module at boot?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: anyone ? I appreciate all kind of feedback

Answer (score 3):

I'm loading needed modules at boot, after creating a file xxx.conf in /etc/modules-load.d/ , where xxx.conf is free-form file name and the content of the file is in form :

```
module1
module2
modulen
```

Regards!